# How to use plist array infos for localise?

Tags: ios, objective-c, internationalization, plist, nslocalizedstring

Hello i have a workspace that 2 projects work parallel. I wanna use Project-2 plist file infos for use in localized.strings file inside Project-1. I am not sure the right way of doing this. Could you give me some ideas please?

Project 2-
plistCamera.plist

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>Icon</key>
    <string>icon_lotr</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>See the LOTR code</string>
    <key>Image</key>
    <string>lotr-help-01</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Please ensure that the lotr code of the document is fits in the screen.</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>Icon</key>
    <string>icon_lotr</string>
    <key>Image</key>
    <string>mrz-help-lotr2</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>The direction of the code is not important.</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

project2Camera.m

```
helpControler.helpContent = NSLocalizedString(@"plistCamera", nil);
```

Project 1- (Turkish language)
localized.strings

```
/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */
"Title" = "LOTR koduna bakalim";
```

Comment: Actually what do you want to do?You have pist.Do you want to localized the string?

Comment: I wanna use another plist file from another project. That project is also in my workspace. But i wanna keep that project private and wanna use only its plist to localize infos from that plist. @user3182143

Comment: It is hard to use the plist from another project.If you have two plist files in same project we can acheive.

Comment: humm so you say there is no possible way to use another project's plist file info in my current project.. :/  Or do we have any option to use different plist file in same project ? Maybe i can get something from it? @user3182143

Comment: Show me your Turkish langulage all list

Comment: Do you want sample code?

Comment: Yes if possible that would be perfect. @user3182143

Comment: when do you want the sample code?

Comment: Whenever you can give me.. @user3182143

Comment: Are you there  now?

Comment: Now I am here.Are you there now?